# How to correctly intercept and handle when the user quit a Java console application?

Tags: java, shutdown, java-threads, application-shutdown

I am working on a simple console application and I have the following problem: I have to intercept and perform an operation when the user close the application (for example clicking **CTRL+C** in the shell).

From what I have understand I can use the **addShutdownHook()** method on my runtime (but I am absolutly not sure about this assertion) but it is not working for me.

I have done something like this:

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("STOPPED !!!");
            }


        });

        ...................................................................
        ...................................................................
        MY APPLICATION BEHAVIOR
        ...................................................................
        ...................................................................
    }
}
```

Doing in this way I expected that the application have to start and then when the user quit the application by **CTRL+C** it enter into the **run()** method defined into the **new Thread()**

What happens is that if I terminate my application pressing **CTRL+C** the application quit but the **run()** method is not performed and so the application end is not handled

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can correctly intercept when the user quit my console application?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I did a wrong assertion, I edited my original post. Basically what happens is that the application normally starts but quitting it by CTRL+C the application end is not handled and the run() method is not performed

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about the "APPLICATION BEHAVIOR" part. What does it do? Perhaps it prints a lot of stuff, so that you don't see the print from the shutdown hook?

Answer (score 4):

I tried the below code and it is working for me when pressing Ctrl+C please note that the addShutDownHook() method should be called before the user press Ctrl+C, as noted in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-):

> Once the shutdown sequence has begun it is impossible to register a new shutdown hook or de-register a previously-registered hook. Attempting either of these operations will cause an IllegalStateException to be thrown.

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String text = "kkkk";
                    Files.write(Paths.get("./fileName.txt"), text.getBytes());
                    System.out.println("STOPPED !!!");
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("the entered int: " + i); // will print the variable



        System.out.println("my app behaviour");

    }
}
```

when the app start and I press Ctrl+C a file is written on the current directory and I can see the following output:

> Pedros-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow pedro$ java -jar target/stackoverflow-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
>   ^CSTOPPED !!!